# Insert Space after 4 Chars in Blazor

Tags: c#, html, textbox, blazor

I have a TextBox in which a variable is set. Now I want to enter a space " " after 4 characters without having to press "Enter". In JavaScript it works like this (its a example, where every 4 chars a "-" is inserted:

"https://jsfiddle.net/juspC/126/"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick - I used `-` symbol instead of space for better readability on output for this example.

```
@page "/"

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<p>@text</p>

<input value="@text" @oninput="onin"/>


@code
{
    public string text;

    public void onin(ChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        var data = args.Value.ToString().Replace("-", "");

        var groups = data.Select((c, index) => new {c, index})
                .GroupBy(x => x.index/4)
                .Select(group => group.Select(elem => elem.c))
                .Select(chars => new string(chars.ToArray()));

        text = string.Join('-', groups);
    }
}
```

Here You have the [Fiddle](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/yzigblev)

Edited: Fixed multi-dashing, updated fiddle, solution works for non-numerics also, excluding `-`.

Comment: Think that should be `<input value="@text" @oninput="onin"/>` ?

Comment: If you remove the `@` from before value, You will get a gibberish output with multi-dashed (?) string in this case.

Comment: there is no `@value` property on an `<input>` in Blazor, so `@value` is meaningless. The repeated value is because the `onin` doesn't strip the dashes before reformatting.

Comment: Updated fiddle: https://blazorfiddle.com/s/9l5zxqmz - I added a Regex.Replace to strip out non-digits, this fixes it

Comment: Thanks for your help. But is it possible, to not remove the non-digit chars?
It would be perfect, to remove special characters (!"$§&%). 
Ive tried it, but it did not work the way i wanted.

Comment: @MaxB - updated my solution and fiddle, should work like You wanted it.

@Quango - `@value` seems to be needed for this to work, control is displaying updated data from this (You also have it in Your fiddle).

Answer (score 1):

Note sure if you want chars or just numerics - your question is chars.  Here's a custom `InputBase` that places hyphens in at every 4th letter:

```
@inherits InputBase<string?>
<input @attributes="AdditionalAttributes"
       class="@CssClass"
       value="@stringValue"
       @oninput="OnInput"
       @onchange="this.OnValueChanged" />

@code {
    private string stringValue;
    private ValidationMessageStore _parsingValidationMessages;

    protected override bool TryParseValueFromString(string value, out string? result, out string validationErrorMessage)
    {
        result = value.Replace("-", string.Empty);
        validationErrorMessage = string.Empty;
        return true;
    }

    private void OnInput(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        var v = e.Value.ToString().Replace("-", string.Empty);
        var a = v.ToCharArray();
        var val = string.Empty;
        for (var x = 1; x <= a.Length; x++)
        {
            val = $"{val}{a[x - 1]}";
            if (x % 4 == 0)
                val = val + "-";
        }
        this.stringValue = val.Trim('-');
    }

    protected async Task OnValueChanged(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        await this.SetValue(e.Value.ToString());
    }

    private async Task SetValue(string value)
    {
        value = value.Replace("-", "");
        // Check if we have a ValidationMessageStore
        // Either get one or clear the existing one
        if (_parsingValidationMessages == null)
            _parsingValidationMessages = new ValidationMessageStore(EditContext);
        else
            _parsingValidationMessages?.Clear(FieldIdentifier);

        // Set defaults
        string? val = value;

        // check if we have a valid value
        await this.ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(val);
        this.Value = val;
        EditContext.NotifyFieldChanged(this.FieldIdentifier);
    }
}
```

You'll need to tune the output if you want the hypens in the value that is passed to the bind value.  If you want only digits you'll need to tune `OnInput` to remove any none digits from `e.Value`.

Note: This is a quick refactoring of code from a similar but different problem so may need a little cleaning up!

Answer (score -1):

If the input string is numeric, you can use the [Format](https://blazor.syncfusion.com/documentation/numeric-textbox/formats) property. Otherwise, you have to use either javascript, format the string in the controller, or [customize the TextBox](https://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/blazor-textbox-customization-a-complete-guide.aspx).